# How to populate number for missing dates?

Tags: mysql

I have a table that look like this

```
date    counts
Sep-01   1  
Sep-05   5
Sep-10   30
```

As you can see the dates are jumping across and is not continuous. I want the final results to be populated for all calendar dates, and the value for the missing dates should be equal to the previous date. I played around with several SQL analytics functions but it doesn't seem to solve the problem. Any tips?

```
date    counts
Sep-01   1
Sep-02   1 
Sep-03   1 
Sep-04   1 
Sep-05   5
Sep-06   5
Sep-07   5
Sep-08   5
Sep-09   5
Sep-10   30
Sep-11   30
...
```

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: outer join a recursive cte generating the dates.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution:

```
CREATE TABLE datadate(startdate DATETIME, cnt INT);

INSERT INTO datadate VALUES('2020-05-25',1);
INSERT INTO datadate VALUES('2020-05-27',2);
INSERT INTO datadate VALUES('2020-05-30',5);

SELECT * FROM datadate;


WITH RECURSIVE  cte_name (cnt,ddate) AS (
 SELECT cnt,MIN(startdate) AS ddate FROM datadate 
           UNION ALL               
           SELECT  
           CASE
           WHEN (SELECT cnt FROM datadate WHERE startdate=DATE_ADD(ddate, INTERVAL 1 DAY)) IS NULL THEN cnt
           ELSE (SELECT cnt FROM datadate WHERE startdate=DATE_ADD(ddate, INTERVAL 1 DAY))
           END AS cnt,
           DATE_ADD(ddate, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
           FROM     cte_name
           WHERE    ddate < (SELECT MAX(startdate) FROM datadate)
) 
SELECT * FROM cte_name;
```

Input:

[image]

Output:

[image]